# How to connect from Windows to Ubuntu and launch Nsight?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, putty, xming

From Ubuntu to Ubuntu I would use:

```
ssh -X __username__@__hostname__
nsight
```

And I can see Nsight running on my local desktop while programs are compiled at the remote.

But how to do that from Windows to Ubuntu?

I tried this guide: [tutorial](https://aruljohn.com/info/x11forwarding/).
However it didn't work and I got these errors:

```
xterm
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Cannot assign requested address
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0

nsight
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Cannot assign requested address
Nsight: Cannot open display:
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Cannot assign requested address
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Cannot assign requested address
Nsight: Cannot open display:
Nsight:
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

Then I tried remote desktop connection (built-in Windows) but there is some problem, something probably isn't installed at remote. I don't have sudo access so I can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and run `X` server on Windows machine. Or you can use terminal emulator which incorporate X server like [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) for example.

P.S. No affiliate with the software